# Auto Deployment On Git and Bitbucket using Hooks. Is It Secure, or Is there A Better Way?

Tags: php, git, deployment, bitbucket

I'm looking to use auto deployments on a new project using git and BitBucket. I've looked into using BitBuckets POST hooks and this seems to be a popular option, but I can't find a lot of options currently, and I'm not sure about how secure this is:

A far as I can see you have to set permissions to 777, enable exec(), and according to the tutorial at http://f6design.com/journal/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/ you have to set up a passwordless key:

> Press enter when asked for a passphrase, which will generate a
>   passwordless key. Usually this isn’t recommended, but we need our
>   script to be able to connect to BitBucket without a passphrase

I can find very little about (free) auto-deployments from BitBucket on the whole. Is there another solution apart from hooks that people use? What do you currently use for auto deployments?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a resource I'm trying to implement. Having some issues regarding permissions but this seems to be the best free solution out there based on my research.

http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late but maybe someone searching will find it useful. I have stumbled across this http://brunodebarros.github.io/git-deploy-php/
stupid easy to use and works great, also a free solution and git does not even need to be installed on the server.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could it be possible to put the solution in your answer and not simply a link to it? That would help a lot future readers. Thanks!